# BuddyPress Custom Template Not Working

Tags: wordpress, templates, buddypress

I have created a custom template for each member's individual profile page and stored the file within this file structure within my child theme:

BuddyPress > Members > Single > index.php

It is working fine on my local machine, however when I pushed to production this page is returning a 404 error. I've double checked, and everything looks correct.

I've also updated my .htaccess file, refreshed my permalinks, and double checked that I am indeed using my child theme with the BuddyPress template.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working. There was an issue with the custom url to each member profile page. Instead of using a member's username, Buddypress was looking for 'user_nicename' in the url.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `index.php` in `buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\`.

There is one in `buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\`.

For single profiles, you should use:

```
buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\home.php
```

And place it in your child theme at: `BuddyPress > Members > Single > home.php`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing the name of the file from index.php to home.php didn't work. When I look in the console I'm still seeing a '404 Page Not Found Error.'